# Inner class template circular reference

Tags: c++, templates

Does anyone knows how you can trick the C++ compiler to compile something like that (with the condition that TheObservedObject remains inside MyClass  ):

```
template< typename Type >
class Observabile
{
public:
   typename typedef Type::TheObservedObject TheObject;

   void Observe( TheObject& obj ) {}
};

class MyClass : public Observabile< MyClass >
{
public:
   class TheObservedObject
   {
   };
}
```

Comment: Did you intend to write `typedef Type::TheObservedObject TheObject` instead of `typename typedef Type::TheObservedObject TheObject`?

Comment: The error is that TheObservedObject is not defined. I expect this is happening due to circular compile dependence MyClass->Observabile< MyClass >->Type::TheObservedObject TheObject->MyClass::TheObject. Looks like it can't figure out how to compile it.

Comment: @Purnima no, the `typename` is required to specify that T::Member is a type, not a static variable. Some compilers don't strictly require it, but gcc does and the standard does (iirc?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, that is not directly possible, as `MyClass`, at the point of instantiation of `Observable`, is not yet complete and as such you can't access any `typedef`s. You can work around this by adding a small wrapper:

```
template< typename Type, typename Wrapper >
class Observable
{
public:
   typename typedef Wrapper::TheObservedObject TheObject;

   void Observe( TheObject& obj ) {}
};

struct MyClassWrapper{
   class TheObservedObject
   {
   };
};

class MyClass : public Observable< MyClass, MyClassWrapper>
{
public:
    typedef MyClassWrapper::TheObservedObject TheObservedObject;
};
```

Or generelly just put `TheObservedObject` outside of `MyClass(Wrapper)`.

Comment: Well I know about wrapper solution but I was hooping that you can do it somehow by keeping TheObservedObject defined inside the MyClass. It is unfortunate that you can't forward declare inner classes in C++ :-(.

Answer (score 1):

Neither you can forward declare the inner class nor you can access them as incomplete type from the `template Observable`. However, in such case, you can have one trick.

```
// make inner class external
class TheObservedObject
{
  private: // make everything private
  friend class MyClass;  // make friends with original outer class
};
```

Thus, effectively `TheObservedObject` is accessible only for `MyClass`.

Now you can change `class Observabile<>` accepting 2 parameters and pass the above class also. This might impose certain limitations, but it can be a close match.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `MyClass` is incomplete at the point where `Observable` is instantiated.  However, you could use a traits class.  Something like this might work:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct ObservedObject {};

template<class T>
class Observable
{
public:
    typedef typename ObservedObject<T>::type TheObject;

    void Observe(TheObject& obj) {}
};

class MyClass;  // forward decl

class MyClassObservedObject
{
    // define outside of MyClass
};

template<> struct ObservedObject<MyClass>
{
    typedef MyClassObservedObject type;
};

class MyClass : public Observable<MyClass>
{
    //
    // ...
    //

private:
    friend class MyClassObservedObject;
};
```